# How to Automate Zipping Files on a Network

Tags: javascript, python, vba, zip

I have been trying to write a script to automate zipping folders on a drive. I want to be able to zip 3 folders at a time and then rename the zipped file (on the drive). This takes my computer way too long so I want to write a script that will automatically do this for me at night when I am not when I am not working.

Is this possible? Should I use Java/ Python or VBA for this? Do you recommend any other programming language? Any help will be greatly appreciated - thank you!

Comment: Your best bet is to use Visual Studio as it's built in and you can schedule it on a timer to run at night.

Answer (score 0):

You could use python:

```
import os
import zipfile

def zipdir(path, ziph):
    # ziph is zipfile handle
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            ziph.write(os.path.join(root, file),
                       os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, file),
                                       os.path.join(path, '..')))


def zipit(dir_list, zip_name):
    zipf = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_name, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    for dir in dir_list:
        zipdir(dir, zipf)
    zipf.close()

my_directories_to_zip = ['complete/path/dir1', 'complete/path/dir2', 'complete/path/dir3']
destination = 'result.zip'

zipit(my_directories_to_zip, destination)
```

Comment: can you elaborate on what my_directories_to_zip = ['complete/path/dir1', 'complete/path/dir2', 'complete/path/dir3']
destination = 'result.zip' means? sorry this is my first time!

Comment: No problem; my_directories_to_zip is a list of paths that you wish to add to the zip. It's a list as you might want to zip multiple paths. destination is simply the path that you wish to save the results to. These two variables are passed to the method zipit which then iterates over the paths in my_directories_to_zip and uses destination to output the result. Feel free to start a chat if you have more questions.